# How do I call WIN API from C#

Tags: c#, api

How do I call `PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification` API in C#?

I need to translate it from C++ to C#.

```
DWORD WINAPI PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification(
  _In_   DWORD Flags,
  _In_   HANDLE Recipient,
  _Out_  PHPOWERNOTIFY RegistrationHandle
);
```

Comment: @Aaronaught, one thing to note is that pinvoke.net does not have [that function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh769080%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) listed under the `powrprof.dll` category. However [knowing how to do P/Invoke methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on your own is a good skill to have.

Comment: To the OP, I just want to make sure you are aware that the API you are talking about is only available on Windows 8 and Server 2012, so it would not work on Windows 7 or older. Are you?

Answer (score 2):

There is a System Event you can use to hook into this method: [PowerModeChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged.aspx).

This allows you to hook into the event and perform some actions before the system Suspends or Resumes.

Comment: Thnaks, but the mode event args has 3 values Suspend, Resume and StatusChange. So How can I know if the event was fired from the connected standby or other states

Comment: The way I have used it previously was to attach to the event and assume that the Suspend event was fired from either the computer going into sleep or hibernate and the Resume would be when the user interacts with the computer to wake it up again.

Comment: Actually the event is not fired when the system goes from normal to connected standby state. So, this is not a solution for my problem.